# Uninstall build dependencies using apt-get

Tags: apt, uninstall, compiling

To install the build dependencies of some software, we use command

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep XXXX
```

What to do in case we want to remove those packages only, those dependency packages installed by build-dep?

Answer (score 2):

In order to find a package dependecies you can use apt-rdepends, to install run:

`sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends`

How to use: `sudo apt-rdepends [options] [pkgs ...]`

For example: `apt-rdepends bash` will print a list like this:

```
bash
  Depends: base-files (>= 2.1.12)
  Depends: debianutils (>= 2.15)
  PreDepends: dash (>= 0.5.5.1-2.2)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  PreDepends: libtinfo5
base-files
  PreDepends: awk
awk
debianutils
  Depends: sensible-utils
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  ...
```

you can find these dependencies with `apt-rdepends` and then remove them by:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge [PACKAGE_NAME]`

Comment: but I want to uninstall them, the files I downloaded for building the dependency of the package, say vlc

Comment: will i have to remove all files one by one? Any utility for removing them at once?